# Shortest Distance Between A Hyperboloid of Two Sheets

Tags: calculus

[The given equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jHFk.png)

Given the equation -x^2 + 8x - y^2 - 10y + (z^2)/25 = 45, I was able to identify that this is a hyperboloid of two sheets centered at (4, -5, 0). I "revised" the equation to be - (x-4)^2/a^2 - (y+5)^2/b^2 + z^2/(5)^2 = 4,

Now I'm being asked to find the shortest distance between the two sheets and I have no idea how to do that. The textbook doesn't say how and we aren't provided any examples. I looked up this exact problem online and couldn't find any answers or examples for these types of questions. Most relevant thing was a research paper.

Comment: Have you seen a picture of a hyperboloid of two sheets?  From that picutre, it is fairly evident which two points are used for the requested distance.  Would you be able to answer the same question for the distance between the two connected pieces of a hyperbola (in the plane)?  Do you recognize that the hyperbola of two sheets is the surface of revolution of the hyperbola around the line connecting the two points of minimal separation...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well, what is the closest point on either sheet to the center point?